Bootstrap Table is not acting responsive to the width of the Browser
Im using Bootstrap for the responsive tables on my front end, ive had a lot of problems correctly formatting the data and so my JS code is pretty lengthy, im just wandering due to all of the challenges, if the JS code is stopping the front end responsiveness as my other tables scretch nicely to the width of the card element but this table is refusing to react in the same way, any ideas what could be causing the issue?
This is my front end
<!-- Content area -->
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="tab-content flex-1 order-1 order-lg-1">
                        <div class="tab-pane active show" id="skulists">
                            <!-- Sku table -->
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="table-responsive"> 
                                        <table class="table datatable-select-single" id="skulist-table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Sku</th>
                                                    <th>Description</th>
                                                    <th>Owner</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Inner UOM</th>
                                                    <th>Outer UOM</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="sku-table-body">
                                                <!-- Rows will be added by JavaScript -->
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /sku table -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" style="di

This is my JS code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Fetch the initial SKU list and populate the table when the DOM is ready
    fetchInitialData();

    // Event listener for the SKU list card on double click
    setupDoubleClickEventListener();

    // Event listener for the "SKU Lists" navigation button
    setupNavButtonEventListener();
});
// Fetch the initial SKU list and populate the table when the DOM is ready
function fetchInitialData() {
    fetch('assets/php/sku/sku_retrieve.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Fetched SKU Data:", data);
            updateSkuListInDOM(data); // Update DOM and initialize DataTable
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching initial SKU list:', error);
        });
}


function setupDoubleClickEventListener() {
    const skuListTableElement = $('#skulist-table tbody');

    skuListTableElement.on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
        var table = $('#skulist-table').DataTable();
        var data = table.row(this).data(); // Gets the data for the clicked row
        if (data) {
            var skuName = data[0]; // Assuming the SKU code is in the first column
            console.log("Row double-clicked: ", skuName);
            loadSkuDetails(skuName);
        }
    });
}


function setupNavButtonEventListener() {
    const skuListsNavButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav-link[href='#skulists']");
    skuListsNavButton.addEventListener("click", switchToSkuListsTab);
}

// Load SKU Details data based on the row double clicked from the SKU list card
function loadSkuDetails(skuName) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var requestUrl = "assets/php/sku/selected_sku_display.php?sku=" + encodeURIComponent(skuName);
    xhr.open("GET", requestUrl, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log("XHR Response:", xhr.responseText);
            try {
                var skuDetails = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                populateSkuDetailsForm(skuDetails);
                switchToSkuDetailsTab();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Failed to parse response as JSON.", e);
            }
        } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.error("Request failed.", xhr.status, xhr.statusText, xhr.responseText);
        }        
    };

    xhr.send();
}

// Populate the SKU details card with table values retrieved from the database
function populateSkuDetailsForm(skuDetails) {
    var detail = skuDetails;
    document.querySelector('[name="sku"]').value = detail.sku_code || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="description"]').value = detail.description || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="inner-height"]').value = detail.height || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="inner-width"]').value = detail.width || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="inner-length"]').value = detail.length || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="inner-weight"]').value = detail.weight || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="inner-uom"]').value = detail.inner_uom || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="outer-uom"]').value = detail.outer_uom || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="outer-height"]').value = detail.outer_uom_height || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="outer-width"]').value = detail.outer_uom_width || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="outer-length"]').value = detail.outer_uom_length || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="outer-weight"]').value = detail.outer_uom_weight || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="box-qty"]').value = detail.box_quantity || '';
    document.querySelector('[name="is-expiry-enabled"]').checked = detail.is_expiry_enabled == 1; 
    document.querySelector('[name="is_production_date_enabled"]').checked = detail.is_production_date_enabled == 1;
    document.querySelector('[name="is_batch_enabled"]').checked = detail.is_batch_enabled == 1;
    document.querySelector('[name="is_serial_enabled"]').checked = detail.is_serial_enabled == 1;

}

// function to switch to the "SKU Details" card
function switchToSkuDetailsTab() {
    var skuListsTab = document.getElementById("skulists");
    skuListsTab.classList.remove("active", "show");

    var skuDetailsTab = document.getElementById("skudetails");
    skuDetailsTab.classList.add("active", "show");
    skuDetailsTab.style.display = "block";

    // Adjust the buttons' active state
    var skuListsNavButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav-link[href='#skulists']");
    skuListsNavButton.classList.remove("active");
    
    var skuDetailsNavButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav-link[href='#skudetails']");
    skuDetailsNavButton.classList.add("active");
}

// function to switch back to the "SKU Lists" card
function switchToSkuListsTab() {
    var skuListsTab = document.getElementById("skulists");
    skuListsTab.classList.add("active", "show");

    var skuDetailsTab = document.getElementById("skudetails");
    skuDetailsTab.classList.remove("active", "show");
    skuDetailsTab.style.display = "none";

    // Adjust the buttons' active state
    var skuListsNavButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav-link[href='#skulists']");
    skuListsNavButton.classList.add("active");

    var skuDetailsNavButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav-link[href='#skudetails']");
    skuDetailsNavButton.classList.remove("active");
}

document.querySelector('#skuDetailsForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(this);
    
    fetch('assets/php/sku/update_sku.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            alert('SKU update was successful!');
            refreshSkuList(); // Call function to refresh the list of SKUs
            switchToSkuListsTab(); // Switch back to SKU list tab
        } else {
            alert('SKU update failed!');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        alert('Something went wrong!');
    });
});

// Function to refresh the list of SKUs
function refreshSkuList() {
    fetch('assets/php/sku/sku_retrieve.php') // Make sure this PHP script returns the updated list of SKUs
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        updateSkuListInDOM(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

function updateSkuListInDOM(skus) {
    const skuListTableElement = $('#skulist-table').DataTable();

    skuListTableElement.clear(); // Clear existing data

    // Dynamically add new rows
    skus.forEach(sku => {
        skuListTableElement.row.add([
            sku.sku_code, // SKU Code
            sku.description, // Description
            sku.owner_id,
            sku.status,
            sku.inner_uom,
            sku.outer_uom
        ]);
    });

    skuListTableElement.draw(); // Redraw the table with new data
    initializeDataTable(); // Initialize or adjust DataTable as necessary
}


function initializeDataTable() {
    if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#skulist-table')) {
        $('#skulist-table').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            scrollX: true
        });
    } else {
        // If already initialized, just redraw
        const table = $('#skulist-table').DataTable();
        table.columns.adjust().draw();
    }
}



tried adding the   to the front end code, my other tables dont seem to need this to stil be responsive but was worth a shot, although it didnt help.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
